# Changing all server member nicknames with nextcord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I wanted to create a discord bot with python that would nickname all of the server members with a sequential value. However when I run my code I am given this error:

**nextcord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions**

I believe the error means the bot does not have permissions to perform the task I wanted it to but I gave it permissions on the developer portal to change nicknames and moderate members. I also gave the bot an administrator role inside of the server to see if this would fix things but that did not work either.

I think that this might be an error with how my code is written or how I am implementing the commands with the bot but I am unsure. Any help or guidance with this would be strongly appreciated.

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents = nextcord.Intents.all())
prefix = "!"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content[0] == prefix:
        content = message.content[1:]

        if content == "all_nick":
            value = 1
            for member in bot.get_all_members():
                await member.edit(nick = "Member " + str(value))
                value += 1

bot.run("BOT_TOKEN_HERE")
```

Comment: The bot can't change the nickname of administrators of the server. Is it not working at all? Try to build in a `try / except` statement in your `for` loop and `continue` if you have an `exception`

Comment: As mentioned, you probably can't do that to the owner of the guild or anyone with higher roles than you. Wrap it in `try` and `except discord.errors.Forbidden: pass` to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This command will change nick of guild members
@bot.command()
async def nickall(ctx, nick):
 for members in ctx.guild.members:
  await members.edit(nick=nick)


#This command will change nick of all guild members
@bot.command()
async def nickallservers(ctx, nick):
 for guilds in bot.guild:
  for members in guilds.members:
   await members.edit(nick=nick)
```

For discord.py or any rewrite help join [Support server](https://araki.social/support)